# iPad Storyboard How to give desired size to modal view controller

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, storyboard, ios

How to change the size of a modal view controller in iPad storyboard. In my iPad app I need to show a modal view controller which has to look like a huge popup. In the storyboard, in the attribute inspecter I set the size of the modal view controller to Freeform and presentation as Form Sheet then I changed the modal view controller's view height. But the height is not changed. Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have to do it programmaticaly within the viewDidAppear of your modal view controller according to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298378/ipad-custom-size-of-modal-view-controller). I usually trust more what set up in my code than in IB.

Answer (score 1):

In IB, choose the modal view controller, open the attribute inspector on the right side bar. Change the Size under simulated metrics to something like freeform. Now you should be able to change the view size of your modal view controller.