# Editing bounds of UIView when presenting hides keyboard in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiview, keyboard

I present a small "login" `UIViewController` as a `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` with custom bounds. In the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method, I change the size of the view to (300,250). This has worked in iOS 5/6/7 but no longer works in 8.

When the view is presented and a `UITextField` is tapped, the app becomes unresponsive (not frozen, just not responding to touches). Almost as if the keyboard is presented but not appearing. Delegate methods ARE called correctly. If I remove the `self.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 250);` from the `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method the keyboard works, but the view is now a full sized `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` style.

This only happens in iOS 8, so I can only assume its an issue with the way the keyboard is presented and the way I am masking/resizing the view, but I'm at a loss as to the solution.

Presenting ViewController -

```
UserLoginViewController *loginVC = [[UserLoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UserLoginViewController" bundle:nil];
loginVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
loginVC.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:loginVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Editing the view bounds -

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {

    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    self.view.superview.layer.cornerRadius  = 10.0;
    self.view.superview.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 250);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In iOS8 You shouldn't change superview bounds in viewWillLayoutSubviews because it causes infinite loop.

EDIT:
in iOS8 property preferredContentSize works well.

You should change your code in that way:

```
  UserLoginViewController *loginVC = [[UserLoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UserLoginViewController" bundle:nil];
    loginVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    loginVC.delegate = self;
    if(IS_IOS8)
    {
        loginVC.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 250);
    }
    [self presentViewController:loginVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Editing the view bounds -

```
 - (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    self.view.superview.layer.cornerRadius  = 10.0;
    self.view.superview.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    if(!IS_IOS8)
    {
        self.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 250);
    }
}
```

Another way, which gives you more customization options is to use UIPresentationController and UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate. Take a look at my code below.

Parent view controller:

```
 _aboutViewController = [[AboutViewController alloc] init];
        _aboutViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
        if(IS_IOS8)
        {
            if(aboutTransitioningDelegate == nil)
            {
                aboutTransitioningDelegate = [[AboutTransitioningDelegate alloc] init];
            }
            _aboutViewController.transitioningDelegate = aboutTransitioningDelegate;
            _aboutViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
        }
        [self presentViewController:_aboutViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

AboutViewController.m

```
#import "AboutViewController.h"

@interface AboutViewController ()

@end

@implementation AboutViewController

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    if(IS_IOS8)
    {
        return;
    }
    CGSize displaySize = CGSizeMake(320, 462);

    self.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, displaySize.width, displaySize.height);
}

@end
```

AboutTransitioningDelegate.h:

```
@interface AboutTransitioningDelegate : NSObject <UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate>

@end
```

AboutTransitioningDelegate.m:

```
#import "AboutTransitioningDelegate.h"
#import "AboutPresentationController.h"
@implementation AboutTransitioningDelegate

-(UIPresentationController *)presentationControllerForPresentedViewController:(UIViewController *)presented presentingViewController:(UIViewController *)presenting sourceViewController:(UIViewController *)source
{
    return [[AboutPresentationController alloc] initWithPresentedViewController:presented presentingViewController:presenting];
}
@end
```

AboutPresentationController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AboutPresentationController : UIPresentationController

@end
```

AboutPresentationController.m

```
#import "AboutPresentationController.h"

@implementation AboutPresentationController


-(CGRect)frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView
{
    CGSize displaySize = CGSizeMake(320, 462);

    if([[Config sharedInstance] latestVersionFromAppstoreInstalled])
    {
        displaySize = CGSizeMake(320, 416);
    }

    CGRect  r =  CGRectZero;
    r.size = displaySize;
    r.origin.y = self.containerView.bounds.size.height/2 - displaySize.height/2;
    r.origin.x = self.containerView.bounds.size.width/2 - displaySize.width/2;
    return r;

}
-(void)containerViewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super containerViewWillLayoutSubviews];
    self.presentedView.frame = [self frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView];
}

@end
```

ProjectName-Prefix.pch

```
#define IS_IOS8 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8)
```

Comment: So does this code need to be added alongside my old code? iOS 7 didn't include this, so I'd need to say "if iOS 8, use UIPresentationController else edit superview? Correct? Seems kind of suboptimal.

Comment: I had a similar problem to your and in this way it solved. If you use iOS 8 sdk, then viewWillLayoutSubviews behaves differently so it seems that we should check system version and in iOS8 use UIPresentationController.

Comment: I have used the first approach, using preferedContectSize property it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to call `containerViewWillLayoutSubviews()` is to call:

```
containerView?.setNeedsLayout()
```